# httpclient: got status 200 amen! now what?

Tags: java, android, apache, http-headers

I am new to programming, please have patience - I successfully done a POST to a web service, but now I want to see the data I got back, how do that? Here is my code:

```
try {
            String data =  "{\"params\":{\"stopName\":\"%lauro linhares%\"}}";

            CredentialsProvider credProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            credProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("WKD4N7YMA1uiM8V", "DtdTtzMLQlA0hk2C1Yi5pLyVIlAQ68"));
            //
            DefaultHttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
            http.setCredentialsProvider(credProvider);

            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://api.appglu.com/v1/queries/findRoutesByStopName/run");
            try {
                post.setEntity(new StringEntity(data, "UTF8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                System.out.println( "UnsupportedEncoding: "+ e);
            }

           post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
           post.addHeader("X-AppGlu-Environment", "staging");

           HttpResponse response = http.execute(post);

            System.out.println("hi! This is what we get back:"+response.getStatusLine().toString()+", "+response.getEntity().toString());
            //Hi! This is what we get back:HTTP/1.1 200 OK, org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity@4246cb88

// got status 200, which is good, but what can
//  I write next to see the 
//data i got back from web service ?



        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //
            System.out.println( "nadir Client protocol exception" + e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //  
            System.out.println( "nadir IOException"+ e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
String str =  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely what you want to do is extract the response from the HttpMethod that was executed. There are a few different methods within the HttpMethod for this, but I imagine you just want to do

```
String response = post.getResponseBodyAsString();
```